# Does not save email field in database

Tags: python, django

After the implementation of checking email for uniqueness, the field is no longer saved in the database

> forms.py

```
class Register(UserCreationForm):

def clean_email(self):
  super().clean()
  email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
  if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
      msg = "Этот адресс уже зарегестрирован."
      self.add_error('email', msg)

class Meta:
  model = User
  fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

> views

```
class MyRegisterFormView(FormView):
# Указажем какую форму мы будем использовать для регистрации наших пользователей, в нашем случае
# это UserCreationForm - стандартный класс Django унаследованный
form_class = Register

# Ссылка, на которую будет перенаправляться пользователь в случае успешной регистрации.
success_url = "/accounts/login/"

# Шаблон, который будет использоваться при отображении представления.
template_name = "registration/register.html"
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(MyRegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form):
    return super(MyRegisterFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `clean_fieldname` needs to *return* the cleaned value. You can for example also perform post-processing in the form:

```
class Register(UserCreationForm):

    def clean_email(self):
      super().clean()
      email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
      if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
          msg = "Этот адресс уже зарегестрирован."
          self.add_error('email', msg)
      return email
    
    class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

You can here use a more specific view as well: a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView). THis will automatically save the form to the database:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class MyRegisterFormView(CreateView):
    # Указажем какую форму мы будем использовать для регистрации наших пользователей, в нашем случае
    # это UserCreationForm - стандартный класс Django унаследованный
    form_class = Register
    # Ссылка, на которую будет перенаправляться пользователь в случае успешной регистрации.
    success_url = "/accounts/login/"
    # Шаблон, который будет использоваться при отображении представления.
    template_name = "registration/register.html"
```